# UCWA Lync authentication - 500 web ticket is invalid

Tags: node.js, lync, ucwa

I'm trying to create a simple client for Lync using Nodejs.
Base on http://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/KeyTasks-CreateApplication I've made someting like this.
It works until last step #9 when I should register my app with UCWA. Server responds with code 500 and silly explanation

> There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed

And headers

> x-ms-diagnostics': '28032;source="mysource";reason="The web ticket is invalid."'

```
var http = require('request-promise');
var lync = {};

lync.setup = function(email, password){
    var self = this;
    var hostname = email.split('@');
    this.username = email;

    //discover urls
    return http.get('http://lyncdiscover.'+hostname[1])
        .then(function(d) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(d);
            self.urls = {
                self: parsed._links.self.href,
                user: parsed._links.user.href,
                xframe: parsed._links.xframe.href
            };
            return http.get(self.urls.user);
        }).catch(function(err){
            if(err.statusCode == 401){
                var toParse = err.response.headers['www-authenticate'];
                var Oauth = toParse.match(/https:\/\/[\d\w\./_-]*/i)[0];

                var loginPost = {
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    username: email,
                    password: password
                };

                return http.post(Oauth, {form:loginPost});
            }
            return false
        }).then(function(data){
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            //setup authorization
            http = http.defaults({
                headers: {Authorization: parsed.token_type + ' ' + parsed.access_token}
            });
            //console.log(self.urls.user);
            //console.log('Authorization:'+ parsed.token_type + ' ' + parsed.access_token);
            return http.get(self.urls.user);

        }).then(function(data){
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            self.urls.applications = parsed._links.applications.href;

            var registerApp = {
                culture : "en-us",
                endpointId : "2d9dc28d-4673-4035-825c-feb64be28e4e",
                userAgent : "Test"
            };
            var r = "{'userAgent': 'NodeJs',  'endpointId' : '2d9dc28d-4673-4035-825c-feb64be28e4e', 'culture': 'en-US'}";
            return http.post(self.urls.applications, {body: registerApp, json:true});
        })
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(err){

            console.log(err);
            return false;
        });
};



//run app
lync.setup('login@domain.com', 'password').then(function(ret){

});
```

One key point here. It's not my server. I just have an account over there and I can login with official Lync client or Pidgin plugin. 
Are there some extra steps to "allow" my app to work with UCWA?

@ShelbyZ
I can easily authorize using Oauth. I'm receiving authorization token so I'm logged in.

I'm receiving json similar to

> "_links":{
>       "self":{"href":"link"},
>       "applications":{"href":"i need this"},
>       "xframe":{"href":"link"}
>   } }

Now. I need to "register my application" doing POST.
In this last step I get 500 code response.
I hope It's not related with that  @Matthew Proctor said..
becouse I cannot simple administrate the server

Comment: Knowing what was contained in the response JSON to the GET request on /Autodiscover/AutodiscoverService.svc/root/oauth/user?originalDomain=domain.com and if the domain portion of the url matched the response would help identify if you are being redirected to a different Lync pool where that original OAuth token would be invalid.  Based on your current information that is the direction that makes the most sense, but there is a lack of context (network traffic leading up to the point where you see the 500 response).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @ShelbyZ
You were right, it was split-domain scenario. Now authorization works, and I can register my app. Also example for future generations

```
var http = require('request-promise');


var lync = {};

lync._authorize = function(){

    var self = this;

    var orgDomain = self.urls.user.match(/https:\/\/([\w\d\.]+)/i)[0];
    //console.log(orgDomain);

    http.get(self.urls.user).catch(function(err){
        if(err.statusCode == 401){
            var toParse = err.response.headers['www-authenticate'];
            var Oauth = toParse.match(/https:\/\/[\d\w\./_-]+/i)[0];

            var loginPost = {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: self.username,
                password: self.password
            };

            return http.post(Oauth, {form:loginPost});
        }
    }).then(function(data){
        if(data) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            //setup authorization
            http = http.defaults({
                headers: {Authorization: parsed.token_type + ' ' + parsed.access_token}
            });
            return http.get(self.urls.user);
        }
    }).then(function(data){
        //check for split-domain scenario
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
        var domain = parsed._links.self.href.match(/https:\/\/([\w\d\.]+)/i)[0];
        console.log('[1] '+orgDomain);
        console.log('[2] '+domain);

        if(domain!== orgDomain){
            //split domain scenario
            self.urls.user = self.urls.user.replace(orgDomain, domain);
            http = http.defaults({
                headers: {Authorization: null}
            });

            self._authorize();
        } else { //create app
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            self.urls.applications = parsed._links.applications.href;

            var registerApp = {
                culture : "en-us",
                endpointId : "2d9dc28d-4673-4035-825c-feb64be28e4e",
                userAgent : "NodeJs client"
            };
            return http.post(self.urls.applications, {body: registerApp, json:true});
        }
    }).then(function(app){
        console.log(app);
    });

};

lync.setup = function(email, password){
    var self = this;
    var hostname = email.split('@');
    this.username = email;
    this.password = password;

    //discover urls
    return http.get('http://lyncdiscover.'+hostname[1])
        .then(function(d) {
            var parsed = JSON.parse(d);
            self.urls = {
                self: parsed._links.self.href,
                user: parsed._links.user.href,
                xframe: parsed._links.xframe.href
            };
            return self._authorize();
        });

};



//run app
lync.setup('username@domain.com', 'password');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error before I added my test domain to the list of Allowed Domains.

This can be updated via PowerShell, full details below:

[Enabling UCWA and Configuring Allowed Domains](https://ucwa.lync.com/documentation/ITAdmin-Configuration)

I've had clients see similar errors when running my code from http://localhost/, their fix was to test their code on a FQDN (ie http://testmyucwacode.mydomain.com/).

Comment: Using node.js would bypass the need to utilize the xframe where the X-Ms-Origin header is added.  When that header is not present, no check can be made against the cross-domain authorization list.